# Display in view image loaded in controller with yii2

Tags: image, model-view-controller, yii2

I'm trying to display in a view an image loaded in a controller (the image folder is not available directly from the view).
I can correctly load the image in the controller but I did not find the correct way in order to provide the view with it.

I tried to exploit the Yii::$app->response solution but it seems useful for the download of the image and not for showing it in the view page.

Controller code (partial)

```
public function actionView($id)
{
     $imgFullPath = '/app/myfiles/img/65/img.jpg';

     return $this->render('view', [
         'model' => $this->findModel($id),
         'imgModel' => Yii::$app->response->sendFile($imgFullPath),
      ]);
}
```

What I need is a way to store in `imgModel` variable the image and then show it in the view

Of course also alternative way are welcome

Can someone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show you image with this code:

```
<?= Html::img('@web/app/myfiles/img/65/img.jpg', ['alt' => 'My image']) ?>
```

Check this - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html section "Images"

If your image is not in web folder - mvoe it or try another way:

in your controller:

```
$imgFullPath = '/app/myfiles/img/65/img.jpg';
$imgContentBase64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgFullPath));
```

in your view:

```
<?= Html::img('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imgContentBase64 , ['alt' => 'My image']) ?>
```

Also you have to check for your MIME type

```
image/jpeg for .jpg and .jpeg files
image/png for .png files
image/gif fir .gif files
```