# Yii2: display image in GridView Widget based on DB

Tags: image, yii2, grid

I have saved images in mysql db using this code

migration file

```
'content' => 'LONGBLOB NOT NULL',
```

controller file

```
$model->content = file_get_contents($model->path);

$model->save(false);
```

in view file and its works fine

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($model->content).'"/>';
```

in gridview

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        
        [

            'attribute' => 'content',
            'format' => ['html'],
            'filter' => false,
            'value' => function ($data) {
                if (!empty($data['content'])) {
                    return Html::img(Yii::getAlias( $data['content'] )
                     ,['data:image/jpeg;base64'=>'.base64_encode']
                );
                }
                return "Not choosen";
            },
    
            ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
    ]); 
?>
```

but there is nothing appearing

Comment: check this my answer how to load img tag with base65 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932881/display-in-view-image-loaded-in-controller-with-yii2

Comment: @vvpanchev I used code like this in view page and it's works fine as i mentioned above `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($model->content).'"/>'; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getAlias is for resolving a file path. You've read your image into the database. Your GridView code is trying to resolve a path, but from the image content you've read into the db, not from the original image on disk.

To display the saved image from the database, use:

```
Html::img('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($data->content),)
```